# Configure custom server for handling oauth 2.0 in spring

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I am totally new to spring and oath 2.0. I want to know where this `/oauth/token` works. In all the examples its shown as `/oauth/token` in configuration file. Suppose i have an external API to handle this functionality, for example `http://mydemo.com/api/oauth/token`. How can i able to configure this in my configuration file. Below is the current configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<!-- Entry Url -->
<sec:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>

<sec:http pattern="/oauth/me" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/me" method="GET" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <sec:access-denied-handler ref="oauthAccessDeniedHandler" />
</sec:http>

<sec:http pattern="/oauth/authorize" create-session="never"
    entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <sec:anonymous enabled="false" />
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/authorize"
        method="GET" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
    <sec:custom-filter ref="userCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
</sec:http>
<!-- End Entry Url -->

<!-- Server -->
<oauth:authorization-server
    client-details-service-ref="clientDetails" token-services-ref="tokenServices"
    authorization-request-manager-ref="SECAuthorizationRequestManager"
    user-approval-handler-ref="SECTokenServicesUserApprovalHandler"
    user-approval-page="forward:/oauth/confirm_access_custom">
    <oauth:authorization-code
        authorization-code-services-ref="JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices" />
    <oauth:implicit />
    <oauth:refresh-token />
    <oauth:client-credentials />
</oauth:authorization-server>

<!-- Resource -->
<oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter"
    resource-id="springsec" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

<bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
</bean>

<bean id="oauthAccessDeniedHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler">
</bean>

<bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="it.oauth.oauthSEC.security.SECClientCredentialToken">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    <property name="clientDetails" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="userCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter" class="it.oauth.oauthSEC.security.SECUserCredential">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="clientDetailsUserService" />
</sec:authentication-manager>

<bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientDetails" class="it.oauth.oauthSEC.security.SECClientDetailsService">
    <property name="id" value="test" />
    <property name="secretKey" value="mycompanykey" />
</bean>

<bean id="SECTokenServicesUserApprovalHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.approval.TokenServicesUserApprovalHandler">
    <property name="tokenServices" ref="tokenServices" />

</bean>

<bean id="SECAuthorizationRequestManager" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.DefaultAuthorizationRequestManager">
    <constructor-arg ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="tokenServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
    <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
    <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
</bean>

<bean id="JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.code.JdbcAuthorizationCodeServices">
    <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate" />
</bean>   

<bean id="tokenStore"
    class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.JdbcTokenStore">
    <constructor-arg ref="jdbcTemplate" />
</bean>   

<bean id="jdbcTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/oauthdb" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
<!-- End Persistence Layer -->

<!-- ModelViewController-->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:default-servlet-handler />

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="it.oauth.oauthSEC.controller" />

<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="htm" value="text/htm" />
            <entry key="html" value="text/html" />
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="viewResolvers">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver" />
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: You could try looking at this [HERE](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples). There should be some config files that implement what you want exactly in regards to OAUTH2 Also May I ask if you have `spring-security` integrated in your webapp? I think you'll sweat a lot if you try to work with OAUTH2 without `Spring-Security`.

Comment: A much cleaner config file of Spring using OAUTH2 would be [HERE](https://github.com/spring-projects/greenhouse/blob/master/src/main/java/com/springsource/greenhouse/config/security-oauth-provider.xml)

Comment: you can refer blog [HERE](http://blog.e-zest.net/rest-authentication-using-oauth-2-0-resource-owner-password-flow-protocol/) for Authentication using OAUTH 2.0 Resource Owner Password Flow protocol